# Setup NetSuite Non-Inventory Item with Avatax

Tags: netsuite, avalara

The NetSuite Non-Inventory item form doesn't seem to have a tax code field for me to populate with the “AVATAX” tax code. Does anyone have experience setting this up and could provide guidance on how to properly do this? My desired outcome is that when entering a transaction (Sales Order or Invoice) the tax code would auto-populate with "AVATAX."

Comment: While not familiar with Avatax, you may be able to set the default tax code under Accounting > Set Up Taxes. There are fields in which the default tax code(s) can be selected.

Answer (score 1):

The custom item field is "AvaTax Tax Code" (*custitem_ava_taxcode*); installed by the AvaTax bundle and *should* create an **AvaTax** subtab on the non-inventory item form.[image: Not-inventory Item for Sale AvaTax Tax Code]